# Nginx exact uri match with separate folder for every URI

Tags: nginx

I have the next catalog tree

```
$pwd 
/var/www/my-site/my-site.com
$tree
.
├── landing_page
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── logo_no_bg_1.png
│   ├── programmer.png
│   ├── scratch.html
│   ├── styles.css
│   └── котик.jpg
└── term_of_service
    └── term_of_service.txt
```

I want that every request to `my-site.com` was returning a `scratch.html` and every request to `my-site.com/term-of-service.txt` was returning `term_of_service.txt`.

How I can do it?

My current config:

```
server {
listen              443 default_server ssl;
server_name my-site.com www.my-site.com;

ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

root /var/www/my-site/my-site.com/ ;
index landing_page/scratch.html;

location term-of-service.txt {
  index term_of_service/term_of_service.txt;
    }

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

Comment: "every request to example.com" - does that mean just `https://example.com` - or does it include `https://example.com/foo` etc.?

Comment: @RichardSmith 1, (only https://example.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Nginx URIs begin with a leading `/`.

Use `location =`  syntax to exactly match a single URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

There are a number of ways to select a single file from within a `location` block. The most explicit is to specify it as the first parameter of a `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
root /var/www/my-site/my-site.com;

location = /term-of-service.txt {
    try_files /term_of_service/term_of_service.txt =404;
}
location = / {
    try_files /landing_page/scratch.html =404;
}
```

---

If you want treat the `landing_page` directory as the document root, the `term_of_service.txt` file would be outside the document root and therefore require its own `root` statement inside the `location` block.

For example:

```
root /var/www/my-site/my-site.com/landing_page;

location / {
    index scratch.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location = /term-of-service.txt {
    root /var/www/my-site/my-site.com/term_of_service;
    try_files /term_of_service.txt =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's also working.
How I can avoid overriding `root` directive for every location?
Why nginx just can't load styles and other files like he loads `scratch.html`?

`root /var/www/my-site/my-site.com; location / { index /landing_page/scratch.html; try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }`